# How to notify PouchDB of changes from a web worker?

Tags: pouchdb

In PouchDB, I have continuous one-way replication running in a web worker, and a [change listener](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) running on the UI thread. When the web worker receives a change from the server and updates the database, the change listener doesn't see it right away. The listener doesn't see it until some other event wakes the listener up, like a UI write. Once it wakes up, listener emits the change and catches up.

Is there any **supported** way to notify the change listener of new changes?

From reading the source code, I came up with this method to wake it up:

1) post message from web worker with last seq:

```js
db.changes().on('change', change => {
  self.postMessage({type: 'notify', seq: change.seq});
})
```

2) handle the message on the UI thread by creating and immediately canceling a continuous change emitter:

```js
worker.onmessage = (e) => {
  const { type, seq } = e.data;
  if (type === 'notify') {
    db.changes({since: seq, continuous: true}).cancel();
  }
}
```

And this works, because [under the covers](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-adapter-idb/src/changes.js#L22) PouchDB does this:

```js
  if (opts.continuous) {
    var id = dbName + ':' + uuid();
    changesHandler.addListener(dbName, id, api, opts);
    changesHandler.notify(dbName); // <-- wake up!
    return {
      cancel: function () {
        changesHandler.removeListener(dbName, id);
      }
    };
  }
```

...and `changesHandler.notify(dbName)` wakes up the change listener. Hooray!

But this seems kind of hacky and fragile. Are there any supported ways to do this?